# How can I write the lines from the first text file that are not present in the second text file?

Tags: python, file, text, readlines

I would like to compare two text files. The first text file has lines that aren't in the second text file. I would like to copy these lines and write them to a new txt file. I would like a Python script for this as I do this a lot and do not want to go online constantly to find these new lines. I do not need to acknowledge if there is something in file2 that is not in file1.

I have wrote some code that seems to work inconsistently. I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
newLines = open("file1.txt", "r")
originalLines = open("file2.txt", "r")
output = open("output.txt", "w")

lines1 = newLines.readlines()
lines2 = originalLines.readlines()
newLines.close()
originalLines.close()

duplicate = False
for line in lines1:
    if line.isspace():
        continue
    for line2 in lines2:
        if line == line2:
            duplicate = True
            break

    if duplicate == False:
        output.write(line)
    else:
        duplicate = False

output.close()
```

For file1.txt:

```
Man
Dog
Axe
Cat
Potato
Farmer
```

file2.txt:

```
Man
Dog
Axe
Cat
```

The output.txt should be:

```
Potato
Farmer
```

but it is instead this:

```
Cat
Potato
Farmer
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using a Linux/Unix OS, the best command for this (not Python) is `comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on behavior, `file2.txt` doesn't end with a newline, so the contents of `lines2` is `['Man\n', 'Dog\n', 'Axe\n', 'Cat']`. Note the lack of a newline for `'Cat'`.

I'd suggest normalizing your lines so they don't have newlines, replacing:

```
lines1 = newLines.readlines()
lines2 = originalLines.readlines()
```

with:

```
lines1 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in newLines]
# Set comprehension makes lookup cheaper and dedupes
lines2 = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in originalLines}
```

and changing:

```
output.write(line)
```

to:

```
print(line, file=output)
```

which will add the newline for you. Really, the best solution is to avoid the inner loop entirely, changing all of this:

```
for line2 in lines2:
    if line == line2:
        duplicate = True
        break

if duplicate == False:
    output.write(line)
else:
    duplicate = False
```

to just:

```
if line not in lines2:
    print(line, file=output)
```

which, if you use a `set` for `lines2` as I suggest, makes the cost of the test drop from linear in the number of lines in `file2.txt` to roughly constant no matter the size of `file2.txt` (as long as the set of unique lines can fit in memory at all).

Even better, use `with` statements for your open files, and stream `file1.txt` rather than holding it in memory at all, and you end up with:

```
with open("file2.txt") as origlines:
    lines2 = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in origlines}

with open("file1.txt") as newlines, open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in newlines:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if not line.isspace() and line not in lines2:
            print(line, file=output)
```

Comment: A shorter choice would be `lines1 = newLines.read().split('\n')`.

Comment: @JuanCarlos: Higher peak memory cost though (needs two copies of the file stored in memory at once). It also leads to empty strings when the file ends in a newline (`.splitlines()` would avoid that problem). Personally, I'd have just streamed `newLines` without ever storing it to a `list` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for smaller and faster solution.
Here we are using these numpy methods
**np.loadtxt** Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html
**np.setdiff1d** Docs:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html
**np.savetxt** Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

```
import numpy as np


arr=np.setdiff1d(np.loadtxt('file1.txt',dtype=str),np.loadtxt('file2.txt',dtype=str))
np.savetxt('output.txt',b,fmt='%s')
```